# Consumer key and secret for connected canvas app

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, canvas, canvas-app

In a managed package we have a Connected canvas app, which will be connected to the central server from all of the Orgs which have installed the package. After the user installs the app exchange app, in the post-installation script, we need to send the consumer key and consumer secret to the central server, so that the server can have access to all the of the Orgs.

Whether the consumer key and secret remains the same across the org?

Answer (score 0):

The Connected App in a Managed Package will always keeps the same consumer key and secret. Store it once in your central server and you should be set for any orgs that install your managed package.

Comment: Thank you! One final question. the canvas app part of managed package is loading fine in the dev org but not on the org in which the package is installed. It always says refused to connect.

Comment: Could be X-frame settings on your server side, and sometimes you have to adjust your CORS / Remote Site Settings / CSP Trusted Sites settings to grant access properly.

Comment: Also - check that you're logged into your external web platform that you're trying to embed into Salesforce via the CanvasApp